# How to modify/ customise NextGen Gallery's templates?

Tags: themes, templates, plugin-nextgen-gallery, template-hierarchy

I would like to customise the "Image browser" template in particular.
I'm trying to make clicking on an image redirects to the next image in a gallery, just like how Facebook image browser works.
(This is not a cosmetic change with CSS - CSS change is not what I mean by customising the tempaltes)

I can always edit `/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/view/imagebrowser.php` but it's a hack and it's not upgradable when next version of NextGen Gallery is out.

Is there anyway I can overwrite the template imagebrowser.php in my theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do that by copying `imagebrowser.php` from /`wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/view/ to yourthemedirectory/nggallery.php`

If you want to customise other templates, you can do the same too.

Some more information can also be found [here](http://www.connectivewebdesign.com/blog/custom-nextgen-gallery-templates-for-wordpress).